# Manage runserver - Error loading MySQLdb module

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

4 Django 1.8 and I have installed pip

I try use command manage runserver but it show me

> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", >line 27, in 
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

I have installed mysql-installer-community-5.7.10.0 
and to fix me problem I try install pip install mysqlclient or mysql-python but I hade the same reasults like on the image below

[CMD printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIoHc.gif)

Comment: Since you are using Python 3 you should use mysqlclient. What error do you get when you try to install it?

Comment: I don't have any idea sow I try do everything. Look on CMD printscreen - link there is this error

Comment: It's much better to post text than screenshots. I see the error after you do `pip install mysql-python`, but that's not helpful because mysql-Python doesn't support Python 3. After `pip install mysqlclient` I just see blank space. What error did you get.

Comment: I know. Today I install fresh Windows and when I install all Python stuff I copy ma old project to Python folder but I should open a new project and now works.

Answer (score 0):

the practice is to install venv :

```
sudo pip install virtualenv 

source env/bin/activate
```

From there you can install first Django and after mysqlclient

```
sudo pip install django

sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

I had that problem also and I was forced to uninstall django and python and reinstall it.

Try to reinstall Django first